# Reading delete keystroke in c

Tags: c, bash, darwin

I have encountered something I don't have a clear grasp on. I am having trouble reading the delete input from my MacBook Air. I am writing a program in c to read the input, and have used the following escape sequence character:

c = '127'

I can set the variable c to the decimal value of 8, which from my understanding is the backspace escape sequence. And also in Terminal>Preferences>Advanced, I check the box that enables delete to send Control-H.

Once I do the mentioned things above, I can read the input setting c variable as the following:

c = '8'

---

Here is my code to attempt to read the delete key from my MacBook
Air:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    /*  Copy program input to program output,
        replacing each tab by \t,
        each backspace by \b,
        and each backslas by \\.
        This makes tabs and backspaces visible in an unambiguous way.
    */

    int c;  // a variable for a character

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\t')
            printf("\\t");
        // check box found in:
        // Terminal>Preferences>Advanced>Delete sends Control-H
        // default setting DOES NOT send Control-H
        // The Delete key does not appear to work with the ascii decimal character value 127.
        if (c == '\127')
            printf("Print to the screen if Delete key is detected.");
        if (c == '\\')
            printf("\\\\");
        if (c != '\t')
            if (c != '\b')
                if (c != '\\')
                    putchar(c);             
    }
}
```

Comment: If you detect `c = 127`, the delete key has been pressed, it is up to you to put `0x8` in the stream to effect the backspace. E.g. if reading from `stdin` then `if ((c = getchar()) == 127) { putchar (0x8); putchar (' '); putchar (0x8);}` to `backspace`, overwrite char to be erased with a `space` and `backspace` again to put the cursor where you want it. If you are not outputting characters (meaning you have output disabled), then a single `putchar (0x8);` is fine.

Comment: I can detect a backspace when I enable the delete key to send  Control-H.

Comment: However I cannot detect the delete character. I have used the ascii character decimal value 127 to attempt to detect the delete key but no luck.

Comment: You should be able to simply `int c = getchar(); if (c == 127) { /* then delete key pressed */};` then it is up to you to handle the `backspace` however you like. Are you saying you cannot trap `c == 127`? That should be a simple comparison (unless the mac does something screwy with the delete key -- always a possibility.) Also, have you put the keyboard in *noncanonical* mode? (otherwise you are pressing return after each keypress??) You shouldn't need to touch `Terminal>Preferences>Advanced`.

Comment: note that `'127'` is *not the same thing as* `127`. And also `'8' != 8`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code and see what happens:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main() {
    int c;
    system("stty raw -echo");
    while (1) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == 3) break;  // exits when Ctrl-C is pressed
        printf("pressed code: %d\r\n", c);
    }
    system("stty -raw echo");
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: shouldn't you handle putting the keyboard in raw unbuffered mode with the functions in `termios.h`? `tcsetattr` specifically?

Comment: That won't be needed because `stty raw` does it, although it would be an orthodox way to make use of the termio functions instead of stty(1).

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you can't read it is that it is not actually there. Using the delete code to delete characters is inefficient, so most programs actually delete the character instead of adding a delete character in order to hide the previous character.

Comment: In response to your comment, out of curiosity then when would you use the delete ascii character value? The number 127 is provided, but not used. To me that doesn't makes sense. I would imagine if you had an ascii character value available then you could use it.

Comment: So is it because that is how it works when you are executing a program?

Comment: @AbrahamMartinez I think it might be used when sending information across the internet or serial ports, since then a code signifying that data is to be deleted would be necessary. This is just a guess, so you should probably search this online.